# Nested List View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

Ok I've seen a lot of questions on accessing the parent listview within a nested listview but none have answered my question.

Why couldn't I access some propery of the first listview and send it to the second?  I've tried lots of different properties but none work.  What about the ItemPlaceHolder or just User_Category?  My thought is to to this with two ObjectDataSoureces and send the DataKeyName from the parent listview to the second ObjectDataSource.  But I don't know how to get the DataKeyName (see the ???? below)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="srcGetOrderForm"
     DataKeyNames=User_Category
     ItemPlaceholderID="lvItemPlaceHolder">

     <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="lvItemPlaceHolder" />
     </LayoutTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelCustomerInfo"
              cssclass="collapsePanelHeaderForFilter"> 
              <%# Eval("User_Category")%>
         </asp:Panel>    
         <asp:panel runat="server" ID="panelCustomerDetails"
              cssclass="collapsePanelForFilter">

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" 
             DataSourceID="srcGetOrderForm2"
             ItemPlaceholderID="lvOrdersItemPlaceHolder">

             <LayoutTemplate>
             <ul>
               <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
                    ID="lvOrdersItemPlaceHolder" />
             </ul>
             </LayoutTemplate>

             <ItemTemplate>
             <li>
                 Description: <%# Eval("Description")%> 
             </li>
             </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:ListView>

      </asp:panel>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="srcGetOrderForm" 
        TypeName = "ABC.Products"
        SelectMethod = "NewGetOrderFormCategories"
        runat="server" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="User" PropertyName="User_ID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="srcGetOrderForm2" 
        TypeName = "ABC.Products"
        SelectMethod = "NewGetOrderFormCategoryItems"
        runat="server" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="User" PropertyName="User_ID" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="User_Category" PropertyName=???? />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Any real need to nest at all? What about ListView Templates, master-details, etc?

Comment: when all said and done, I'll need three seperate groupings.  All the examples I've seen use nested listview.  But I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it all depends on what you mean by "passing", what you want to pass, and when you want to pass the value.

If you want to pass information from the main listview to the child listview, you could override the main listview's `ItemCreated` event. In that event, you can access `Container.DataItem`, which will provide the current object that the row of the parent listview is bound to. You can then use the `FindControl` function to find the inner listview, and interact with it as you see fit. You may not be able to use the `ObjectDataSource`, though. You may have to bind the second listview's datasource directly.

Comment: Is that my problem too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077897/grab-item-id-from-parent-listview