# How to render related items in a child ListView using the item ID from the parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a nested list view and the goal is to pull the ID from outer list view and pass it into the method below as the `CurrentCategoryId` This will allow my second list view to populate correctly. From what i read this should be done with a eventhandler `OnItemDataBound` but i am having trouble understanding how it that works?

Please let me know if you have any questions

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1"
    ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Category"
    runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetCategories"
    OnItemDataBound="brandList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style-type: none; text-align: left;">
                <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                    <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>">
                        <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                    </a>
                    <asp:ListView ID="brandList" runat="server" ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Brand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; text-align: left;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCatBrandRoute", new {brandName = Item.BrandName}) %>">
                                        <%#: Item.BrandName %>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </b>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I think the event handler needs to look like this

```
protected List<Brand> brandList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Category mydata = (Category)dataItem.DataItem;
        int CurrentCategoryId = mydata.CategoryID;
        var query = _db.Products.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryID == CurrentCategoryId).Select(p => p.Brand).Distinct();
        return query.ToList<Brand>();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but gives me the error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<E_Store_Template.Models.Brand> E_Store_Template.SiteMaster.brandList_ItemDataBound(object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs)' has the wrong return type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemDataBound isn't designed to return data, it is designed to handle an event. In this case the event is rendering a category and anything that needs to happen as a child event. The proper course of action is to get the child ListView from the parent item and bind your data to it. Markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="categoryList" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="brandList_ItemDataBound" ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Category" SelectMethod="GetCategories">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li style="text-align: left;">
                <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                    <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>">
                        <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                    </a>
                </b>
                <asp:ListView ID="brandList" runat="server">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; text-align: left;">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
                        </ul>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCatBrandRoute", new {brandName = Item.BrandName}) %>">
                                <%#: Item.BrandName %>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void brandList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Category mydata = (Category)dataItem.DataItem;

        int CurrentCategoryId = mydata.CategoryID;
        var query = _db.Products.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryID == CurrentCategoryId).Select(p => p.Brand).Distinct();

        ListView brandList = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("brandList");
        brandList.DataSource = query.ToList<Brand>();
        brandList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I added LayoutTemplates with PlaceHolders so your ListView doesn't repeat your  tags for each record. I also moved your closing  tag because you shouldn't have a block element (unordered list) as a child of a bold tag set.

I would consider getting all the Categories and Brands in 1 (or 2) SQL queries then filtering the Brands data list by the appropriate CategoryID. You would store the Brands data list as a page level variable, but don't load it into Session or ViewState, you only need it during the page rendering.